# Get Vue component by html element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js

I'm trying to migrate an angularjs app to vue.js

I have a vue component rendered inside angularjs element:

```
<angular-controlled-div>
   <root-vue-element>

       <vue-child-component v-for="athing in parentThings" 
           v-bind:thing="athing"
           v-on:click.native="vueChildComponentMethod" 
           ng-click="angularScopeEventHandler($event)" />

   </root-vue-element>
</angular-controlled-div>
```

First part of the problem is that, besides rendering and data binding works fine in that setup, `v-on:click` - doesn't, vue doesn't attach a listener, I suppose angular kicks in and overwrite it. Angular event handlers works fine.

```
// here is a part of angularjs code
$scope.angularScopeEventHandler = function($event) {
    var evntTarget = $event.target;

    // I would want to get vue component instance here
    getVueComponentForHTMLElement(evntTarget).vueChildComponentMethod();
};
```

One of the answers suggests that vue generated DOM nodes have `__vue__` property, but `evntTarget` element doesn't have any.

Is there a way to get an instance of Vue component by its html element and call a method or access a data or a props?

Vuw is v2.6.10 and AngularJS is 1.7.2

Comment: Can you use [ng-non-bindable](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable) to exclude the vue app from angular? Look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074705/how-can-i-exclude-an-element-from-an-angular-scope)

Comment: @ljubadr tried, but didn't help. It's beeing exluded from scope, but stlill there is only one click event listener `html.ng-scope` but thanks for great directive.